# How to get camel case version of project name with .NET CLI custom templates

Tags: templates, dotnet-cli

I am trying to create a template project for the dotnet CLI and I have a need to alter the format of the project name for some replacements. Specifically, convention within our domain uses a camel-case version of the project name as an identifier that needs to be stored in a configuration file.

Normally the templates perform what appears to be a pretty straightforward search/replace of the template project name to the name of the project you are creating with dotnet new. This search is case-sensitive, so it will only pick up instances of the name with the exact same casing.

However in my case, I need it to match a camel case version of the name as well, and replace it with a camel case version of the new name. Is this possible?

[This reference](https://github.com/dotnet/templating/wiki/%22Runnable-Project%22-Templates#customoperationsvariableformat-optional) has quite a bit of information, and [this](https://github.com/dotnet/templating/wiki/Available-Parameter-Generators) shows that there is a parameter generator that supports upper and lower case conversions, but specifically says it does not support camel casing. All I really need is the ability to change the first character from upper to lower case.

Any idea how I might be able to insert a camel case version of the project name?

Here is my experimental template.json for the upper and lower case, and command line parameter, but obviously nothing for the camel casing.

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/template",
  "identity": "TemplateTest.CSharp",
  "groupIdentity": "TemplateTest.Console",
  "author": "TemplateTest",
  "classifications": [ "Common", "Console" ],
  "name": "TemplateTest console template",
  "shortName": "test",
  "preferNameDirectory": true,
  "tags": {
    "language": "C#"
  },
  "sourceName": "TemplateTest",
  "symbols": {
    "apiname": {
      "type": "parameter",
      "datatype": "text",
      "defaultValue": "##FIX THIS##",
      "replaces": "templateTest"
    },
    "nameUpper": {
      "type": "generated",
      "generator": "casing",
      "parameters": {
        "source": "name",
        "toLower": false
      },
      "replaces": "TEMPLATETEST"
    },
    "nameLower": {
      "type": "generated",
      "generator": "casing",
      "parameters": {
        "source": "name",
        "toLower": true
      },
      "replaces": "templatetest"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Pull request [#1723](https://github.com/dotnet/templating/pull/1723) introduced a(n as-yet undocumented) `join` generator. With this, and the also-undocumented [derived symbols](https://github.com/dotnet/templating/issues/1066#issuecomment-319827279), you can separate the project name into [first letter] and [the rest], convert [first letter] to lowercase, and re-join them. Assuming you are starting with PascalCase, this gives you the name in camelCase.

There is another option to [define regexes which replace each individual uppercase letter](https://github.com/dotnet/templating/issues/1238#issuecomment-476736389).

Below, the symbol `temp1` passes the project name to the custom transform `lowerCaseFirstLetter`, which is itself a combination of the custom transforms `firstLetter` and `lowerCase`. The symbol `temp2` passes the name through transform `afterFirstLetter`.

`firstLetter` and `afterFirstLetter` use the same regex to capture the first letter as `$1` and the rest as `$2`, but return only the first and second capturing group respectively.

Finally, the symbol `apiname` concatenates `temp1` and `temp2`, and uses the result to replace instances of `templateTest` in the template content.

```
"symbols": {
  "temp1": {
    "type": "derived",
    "valueSource": "name",
    "valueTransform": "lowerCaseFirstLetter"
  },
  "temp2": {
    "type": "derived",
    "valueSource": "name",
    "valueTransform": "afterFirstLetter"
  },
  "apiname": {
    "type": "generated",
    "generator": "join",
    "replaces": "templateTest",
    "parameters": {
      "symbols": [
        {
          "type": "ref",
          "value": "temp1"
        },
        {
          "type": "ref",
          "value": "temp2"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
},
"forms": {
  "lowerCaseFirstLetter": {
    "identifier": "chain",
    "steps": [
      "firstLetter",
      "lowerCase"
    ]
  },
  "firstLetter": {
    "identifier": "replace",
    "pattern": "^(.)(.*)",
    "replacement": "$1"
  },
  "afterFirstLetter": {
    "identifier": "replace",
    "pattern": "^(.)(.*)",
    "replacement": "$2"
  },
  "lowerCase": {
    "identifier": "lowerCase"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since .NET 5.0.300 there is a transform "firstLowerCase" and "firstLowerCaseInvariant" you can use.

```
"symbols": {
    "appNameCamelCase": {
        "type": "derived",
        "valueSource": "name",
        "valueTransform": "firstLowerCase"
    }
}
```